# Implementing Update to kotlin data class

Tags: rest, kotlin, crud, data-class

I'm new to Kotlin and i want to build a data class update. my data-class represents a DB document and i need to implement CRUD for it.
so Creating, Reading & Deleting is easy. but how about updating?
i have class :

```
data class RecordType(val id: String, val name: String,
 val description: String, val values: Array<String>, var companyId : String? = "");
```

my controller sends to my service layer the update object:

```
data class UpdateRecordTypeRequestModel (@NotEmpty val id: String,
                                         val name: String?,
                                         val description: String?,
                                         val values: Array<String>?,
                                         var companyId : String?)
```

now I want to update the database according to the fields that changed, assuming i don't know which fields have changed... how will i implement it? In Java i used modelMapper with 
skipNulls = true

Comment: How is this situation different from Java?

Comment: because I want to use kotlin's null safety... and wondering if there is a way of doing it better in kotlin and not use the java null implementation...